# Angular | The authguard blocks all pages

Tags: angular

I need to take the values from a json which returns true or false based on the user type. I debugged and the true and false values are correct, but despite this the urls of the pages don't open. What am I doing wrong?

auth.guard.ts

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<boolean | UrlTree> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let flagErrors: boolean;
      let flagLabels: boolean;
      this.userService.getProfili().subscribe(response => {
        for (var i = 0; i < response.result.length; i++) {
          const id = response.result[i].id;
          if (this.authService.id == id) {
            flagErrors = response.result[i].flagErrors;
            flagLabels= response.result[i].flagLabels;
            break;
          }
        }
        if (flagErrors) {
          this.router.navigateByUrl('/errors');
          return flagErrors
        }
        if (flagLabels) {
          this.router.navigateByUrl('/label');
          return flagLabels
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

app-routing.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'label', component: LabelsComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'errors', component: ErrorsComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
];
```

Comment: You made it loop endlessly. When you attempt to load either route, the guard either returns a boolean AND redirects (which causes the guard to run again, ...), OR it does not return anything at all and does not redirect either.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. So how can I fix my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

U must return values from result, so i use boolean observable ... u must add map from rxjs.

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
return this.userService.getProfili().pipe(map((res) => {
    for (var i = 0; i < res.result.length; i++) {
      const id = res.result[i].id;
      if (this.authService.id == id) {
        flagErrors = res.result[i].flagErrors;
        flagLabels= res.result[i].flagLabels;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (flagErrors && state.url == 'errors') {
      return true
    }
    if (flagLabels && state.url == 'label') {
      return true
    }
    return false
})
```

}

Comment: This is better than the other answer. Checking the URL along with the associated boolean is probably the way to go. Also getting rid of the useless Promise and just returning the Observable is good. Note that you can also return an UrlTree to your fallback or "unauthorized" page instead of the last false)

Comment: It works perfectly, the only thing I had to add is the '/' in `state.url == '/url'`. I'm writing this for those who may test the code and think it doesn't work since it doesn't give any errors in the console.

Answer (score 0):

The code inside the `canActivate` method is not returning the expected value for the guard, which is either a `boolean` value or a `UrlTree` object.

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
return this.userService.getProfili().pipe(map((response) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < response.result.length; i++) {
      const userId = response.result[i].id;
      if (this.authService.id == userId) {
        flagErrors = response.result[i].flagErrors;
        flagLabels= response.result[i].flagLabels;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (flagErrors && state.url == 'errors') {
       return this.router.createUrlTree(['/errors'])
    }
    if (flagLabels && state.url == 'label') {
      return this.router.createUrlTree(['/label'])
    }
    return false
})
```

app-routing.ts

```js
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: '', component: HomeComponent },
{ path: 'label', component: LabelsComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
{ path: 'errors', component: ErrorsComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
];
```

I don't see a point of using `Promise` here only if you need to load it and if so make sure to use `resolve()` method.

Comment: Not sure why you are resolving true as te final else, this doesn't guard anything then...

Comment: I missed that thanks. @Sleepwalker